# Why does replying to this Facebook email address trigger a security warning by Yahoo?

Tags: email

I am developing a Chrome plugin that simplifies various aspects of dealing with the Facebook advertising platform.  As part of this I have experimented with ideas pertaining to dealing with emails from FB support.  In that context I ran into a situation where the mere act of replying to an email received from Facebook (not spoofed, a real email from FB received due to interacting with the platoform) instantly triggers a security warning on the Yahoo email platform.  Replying to this FB email just ONCE triggers a 24 hour ban from Yahoo preventing you from sending emails.  You have to log out and solve a CAPTCHA before you are able to send emails again.

This has happened three times.  Not sure why.  Replying to the following Facebook email address from Yahoo Mail triggers a security alert claiming "suspicious activity":

```
info+w2opo85.aeayqq3dz3idc@support.facebook.com
```

I am not that familiar with the internals of email communications.  Is FB sending some kind of a response to Yahoo that triggers this?  Is there something inherent with the email address that causes Yahoo to trigger an alarm?

**UPDATE:**
I fired-up good-old Outlook and was able to send without problems.  This is the response header I got back:

```
Return-path: <noreply@support.facebook.com>
Envelope-to: --redacted--
Delivery-date: Sat, 18 Oct 2014 07:50:43 -0700
Received: from outmail018.prn2.facebook.com ([66.220.144.145]:2218 helo=mx-out.facebook.com)
    by --redacted-- with esmtps (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:128)
    (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <noreply@support.facebook.com>)
    id 1XfVL9-0007KM-DJ
    for --redacted--; Sat, 18 Oct 2014 07:50:43 -0700
Received: from facebook.com (AZoY0ScZLK/huKiYZ2AvEB3F7ZTivf7rJmnmoP5Y+4qOWkIeAaeuu0z4o1geSJ/D 10.17.112.51)
 by facebook.com with Thrift id 1eed4c9456d611e4af5d0002c9266fc8-48be93e0;
 Sat, 18 Oct 2014 07:50:36 -0700
X-Facebook: from 10.83.20.55 ([MTI3LjAuMC4x]) 
    by async.facebook.com with HTTP (ZuckMail);
Date: Sat, 18 Oct 2014 07:50:36 -0700
To: --redacted--
From: Facebook <noreply@support.facebook.com>
Reply-to: Facebook <noreply@support.facebook.com>
Subject: Re: Test
Message-ID: --redacted--
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: ZuckMail [version 1.00]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=support.facebook.com;
    s=s1024-2013-q3; t=1413643836;
    bh=2OxaQEfrQJk+5tQ3x7l7F2VnmqsWQ1uIk+sBaezsXck=;
    h=Date:To:From:Subject:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
    b=cM5N4TwKSHaDoByO5hEF3m73fdJMqxYYZVV6gSy0z4pWBQJu5gU894iMfqQS0LG7z
     Fm1p/9Eh6hb2qkc7MCjSD/hWtwlDFF9lhETuaiV3Q+ZyDiZR9yrWUZMcKu+6mPad3Q
     a0q6Qf3FL4MCvgej7GRDwUEBrn7mh2wssTSEk668=
```

Message:

```
Hi,

You've reached us at a channel that we don't support. Please visit the Help Center to find answers to many frequently asked questions and up-to-date forms you can use to get in touch with us:

https://www.facebook.com/help

We apologize for the inconvenience. 

Thanks,
The Facebook Team
```

Comment: "ZuckMail" ... gotta love that.

Answer (score 0):

Email spoofing is a pretty common tactic to phish people.  Yahoo probably beefed up their spam filters and the amount of non-word characters and nonsensical hashes is tripping the security alert.

@support.facebook.com is clearly a legit domain, but it's not unheard of for spammers to use a fake support email in order to scam you into giving up personal information.

It's most likely for this reason that the security alert was tripped.

Comment: Answering such obviously off-topic questions is just like feeding a troll.

Comment: I don't think this is off topic.  Just edited the question to provide additional context.